# Attempting to only run code when location services enabled causing infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

My app requires location services and I wish to only run my main method when they are enabled on opening app for first time or were previously enabled.

I am using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == YES) {
        //are enabled, run the JSON request
        [self getDataFromJson];
    } else {
        //is not enabled, so set it up
        NSLog(@"no");
        [locationManager location];
    };

}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    return coordinate;

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        //location denied, handle accordingly
        locationFailView.hidden = NO;
        mainView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        //hooray! begin tracking
        [self getDataFromJson];
    }
}

//class to convert JSON to NSData
- (IBAction)getDataFromJson {
    NSLog(@"running");
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
    ...
}
```

This code works almost perfectly now except for the fact that `getDataForJson` runs again and again, causing an infinite loop (i.e., "running" is output again and again).

How am I going wrong so it only runs once?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this was a little while back, but if mine was a satisfactory answer, perhaps you can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me **getDataFromJson** calls **getLocation**, which allocates a **locationManager** instance, whose delegate calls **locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:,** that calls **getDataFromJson**.  It only happens when location services are enabled because **getDataFromJson** only gets called when status == **kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized**.

**getDataFromJson** -> getLocation ~> locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus (via delegate) -> **getDataFromJson** (when location services are enabled).

Comment: Yes, that's right, and I can see the problem now. The reason I did this is because I need the coordinates in `getDataFromJson`. Is there a better way to this then, as I need to access those coords in `getDataFromJson`?

Comment: This is indeed correct kid_x. And this will create an infinite loop when kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized is true

Comment: @d00dle Thanks for confirming. Do you have any ideas how I would reorganise this to fix it?

Comment: Not sure why you need to call the method in both scopes, but you can make the location manager a strongly-referenced property, and check whether or not it needs allocation, thus avoiding the loop.